# Get annual mean from months by individuals

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large dataset that I need to grab the means for Station_ID over months.

Here is a sample of the data :

```
DF <- read.table(text="Station_ID January February March  April    May  June  July August September October November December Year
1      17578   30.04    12.95 33.29 134.38 167.40 89.48 49.75  65.78     50.15   30.35    70.72    20.68 1896
2      18982   29.66    13.03 33.31 134.20 167.40 89.48 47.64  65.57     49.87   29.98    70.57    20.55 1896"
, header = TRUE)
```

Which produces this :

```
  Station_ID January February March  April   May  June  July August September October November December Year
1      17578   30.04    12.95 33.29 134.38 167.4 89.48 49.75  65.78     50.15   30.35    70.72    20.68 1896
2      18982   29.66    13.03 33.31 134.20 167.4 89.48 47.64  65.57     49.87   29.98    70.57    20.55 1896
```

This is my desired output :

```
  Station_ID AVGPPT_1896
1      17587       62.91
2      18982       60.89
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Could also try `Reduce` as in `Reduce("+", DF[month.name])/ (ncol(DF) - 2)` though it is not clear if every row is unique ID or there could be several rows per ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option, using dplyr and tidyr. Start by reshaping your data from wide to long format (using tidyr's gather function) and then group by Station Id and produce the mean values per month.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(DF, Month, Value, -c(Station_ID, Year)) %>% 
    group_by(Station_ID) %>% 
    summarise(AVGPPT_1896 = mean(Value))

#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#  Station_ID AVGPPT_1896
#1      17578    62.91417
#2      18982    62.60500
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!  Just what I was looking for.  Any chance to use dplyr is always useful in large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
DF$AVGPPT_1896<-rowMeans(DF[,-c(1,ncol(DF))])
```

or

```
DF$AVGPPT_1896<-rowMeans(DF[,month.name])
```

Both give :

```
> DF[,c("Station_ID","AVGPPT_1896")]
  Station_ID AVGPPT_1896
1      17578    62.91417
2      18982    62.60500
```